# Undefined reference Tesseract

Tags: c++, lib, компоновщик, tesseract

Всем привет. Я пытаюсь подключить библиотеку Tesseract OCR для проекта в Qt. Но у меня не получается. Каждый раз появляется ошибка в этом коде :

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *myOCR =
            new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
```

Ошибка:

> undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI()

Как мне кажется, это проблема с подключением библиотек, но я не уверен. Вот код .pro файла:

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/lib/ -llibtesseract302

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/include/tesseract
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/include/tesseract

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/lib/libtesseract302.lib

unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/lib/ -lliblept168

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/include/leptonica
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/include/leptonica

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/lib/liblept168.lib

DEFINES += _tagBLOB_DEFINED
DEFINES += USE_STD_NAMESPACE
DEFINES += WINDLLNAME=\\\"lib$$TARGET.dll\\\"
DEFINES += VERSION=\\\"$$VERSION\\\"
DEFINES -= UNICODE

INCLUDEPATH += C:/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract-ocr/api
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract-ocr/ccmain
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract-ocr/ccutil
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract-ocr/ccstruct
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract-ocr/include

LIBS += C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/liblept168-static-mtdll.lib
LIBS += C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/giflib416-static-mtdll.lib
LIBS += C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/libjpeg8c-static-mtdll.lib
LIBS += C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/libtiff394-static-mtdll.lib
LIBS += C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/zlib125-static-mtdll.lib
```

Каждая функция TessBaseAPI вызывает одну и ту же ошибку.
Я уже долго парюсь с этой проблемой. Можете помочь пожалуйста? Спасибо вам!

Comment: проблема у Вас совершенно точно в том, что не линкуется нужная библиотека. Попробуйте добавить все доступные библиотеки из папки `C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib`, так как у Вас сделано в самом конце: `LIBS += C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/zlib125-static-mtdll.lib`, т.е. с полным путём.

Comment: @newfag, сборки tesseract и leptonica откуда-то брали или собирали самостоятельно? Qt, как я понимаю, у Вас с mingw? Просто тоже сталкивался с этой проблемой. Ни одна из готовых сборок, какие только находил в сети, не работала (если и подключалась в проект, то обязательно программа крашилась на каком-нибудь участке кода). Поэтому собирал самостоятельно, делал динамические. А вообще, в msys2 имеется и tesseract-3.02.02 и leptonica-1.72.

Comment: @alexis031182 Вроде бы все подключил, но появляется ошибка APPCRASH,  связанная с libtesseract-3.dll. Либо, после добавления .dll, появляется другая ошибка компилятора с номером -1072365566. Две ошибки на выбор, вот такой косяк. Если что, на почту скинул вопрос с подробным описанием проблемы. Надеюсь, кто-нибудь еще поможет.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже отметил в своём комментарии к вопросу, брать готовые сборки tesseract из сети и подключать их к своему проекту - это с большой вероятностью бесполезное занятие. Во всяком случае мне в своё время не повезло, хотя я и перепробовал множество различных вариантов.

Мои исходные условия: компилятор `mingw 4.9.1`, входящий в состав `Qt 5.4.1`, на `Windows 7 x86`.

Проблема сборки tesseract на виндовсе заключается в его зависимости от `leptonica`, которая в свою очередь зависит от кучи других библиотек, навроде `libgif`, `libjpeg`, `libpng` и ещё нескольких других. Собирать всё это хозяйство самостоятельно - трудно, без `cygwin` не обойтись. А с ним тоже без пол-литры не разберёшься, тем более когда впервый раз сталкиваешься и не знаешь, что вообще надо скачать на сайте, мягко говоря, с далеко не интуитивно понятным интерфейсом и огромными списками ссылок на разные версии (нужно ведь ещё и помнить о совместимости с mingw в составе Qt).

Знал бы я на тот момент времени о существовании [msys2](http://msys2.github.io/), то и горя бы не знал. Всё, о чём здесь ведётся речь, там уже собрано и готово к использованию. Бери, подключай к проекту и, как говорится, - Enjoy!

Но ранее, я стал искать искать возможность самостоятельной сборки обозначенных библиотек. Решение мною было обнаружено [здесь](http://broija.blogspot.ru/2014/10/compile-tesseract-ocr-30202-with-mingw.html). Автор блога столкнулся с той же проблемой. Он даже нашёл на гитхабе репозиторий, где выложены готовая сборка тессеракта со всеми зависимыми библиотеками. Однако, по его уверениям, эта сборка оказалась для него неработоспособной. Я проверять это утверждение не стал, поскольку уже не было возможности тратить время на бесплодные попытки, и сразу перешёл непосредственно к сборке.

Тем не менее, тот репозиторий оказался всё же полезен. Выложенные там `libgif`, `libjpeg`, `libpng` и т.п. файлы, кроме собственно лептоники и тессеракта, можно и нужно использовать.

Не стану повторяться о том, что написано в блоге, отмечу лишь, что для сборки придётся установить CMake и подредактировать файл `CMakeLists.txt` в соответствии с путями в своей системе. Файл `env.bat`, упоминаемый в мануале, создавать необязательно, т.к. можно использовать консоль фреймворка Qt, которая доступна из меню виндовса после установки последнего. Файл `cmake.bat`, который также упоминается в блоге, можно тоже проигнорировать (у меня с ним, кстати, не пошло), а просто воспользоваться, например, графической программкой `cmake-gui.exe`, идущей в составе CMake.

На этом всё. CMake создаст необходимый `Makefile`. Останется в консоли Qt (напомню: доступна из меню виндовса) зайти в соответствующую папку с исходниками и запустить `mingw32-make.exe` для непосредственно сборки.

[По ссылке](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/205uteit1s37jgs/AADdg6F4F6vm7VXKK88EM11la?dl=0) то, что получилось у меня. Сборка для динамического подключения библиотек.

Напоследок несколько замечаний по подключению и использованию.

В проекте собранный тессеракт достаточно подключать так:

```
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../tesseract_output/include

    LIBS += -L$$PWD/../tesseract_output/bin/ \
        -lliblept-3 -llibtesseract3.02.02
}
```

В коде используйте вызов:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
```

где-нибудь в самом начале своего приложения, лучше всего в функции `main()`. Без этой строки вызов функций тессеракта для распознавания будет крашить программу.

Незабудьте скопировать папку `tessdata` c языковыми файлами в папку с exe-файлом вашей программы. Тогда инициализация объекта тессеракта будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;
tess.Init(NULL, "eng");
```

Либо указывайте её местоположение при вызове функции `Init()` в качестве первого аргумента. Например, так:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;
tess.Init("C:\\path\\", "eng");
```

Обо всём об этом в документации говорится, но часто забывается, а программа в итоге выкидывает непонятное исключение и завершает своё выполнение.

Незабудьте положить рядом с собранным exe-файлом своей программы все *.dll из состава собранных ранее. Всякие `libgif`, `libjpeg`, `libpng` и т.п. Разумеется, что `liblept` и `libtesseract` также потребуется разместить рядом.